# How to use environment variables with HarperDB cloud functions?

Tags: javascript

How to make use of environment variables in HarperDB cloud functions? I have a secret value that I need to save secretly as an env variable. Adding a `.env` file and using `dotenv` library to read the value doesn't seem to work in the function.

What is the right way to use `process.env` inside the cloud functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Custom Function server is managed by HarperDB, so it looks for a `.env` file located at HarperDB's root.

The solution is to set the `path` value when you invoke `dotenv`config :

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: '/path/to/hdb/custom_functions/myproject/.env' })
```